# sort a delimited string by json field

Tags: jquery, json, sorting, token

I have an example at http://verlager.com/demo.php

The data is read and displayed by this javascript:

```
let dataString = "Worl, Seymour|Jones, Jim|Smith, Paul|Jolly, Roger|";
let splitString = dataString.split("|");

for (let i = 0; i < splitString.length;) {
    $("#I" + i).val(splitString[i-1]);  i++;
}
```

and the supporting json:

```
var standing = [
    {"code" : "A", "rank" :  "1"},
    {"code" : "B", "rank" :  "2"},
    {"code" : "C", "rank" :  "3"},
    {"code" : "D", "rank" :  "4"}
];

var members = [
    {"Class": "A", "Name": "Jolly, Roger"},
    {"Class": "B", "Name": "Smith, Paul"},
    {"Class": "C","Name": "Jones, Jim"},
    {"Class": "D","Name": "Worl, Seymour"}
];
```

I want: "Worl, Seymour|Jones, Jim|Smith, Paul|Jolly, Roger|";

to become "Jolly, Roger|Smith, Paul|Jones, Jim|Worl, Seymour|";

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the relationship. If I understand, you get a data string that contains `|` as the delimiter and you want to sort the string based on a JSON structure?

Comment: Yes. Using each token from the dataString, lookup members[Name], get the members[Class] and lookup standing[rank] based on standing[code]

Comment: I think this question is unclear—what is the _question_?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your comment on how you want the code to operate, I think this will do the job for you. I'm assuming that `code` in the `standing` array is the same as `class` in the `members` array. Names which are not found in the members list will be ranked at the bottom.

```
let dataString = "Worl, Seymour|Jones, Jim|Smith, Paul|Jolly, Roger|";
let splitString = dataString.split("|");

var standing = [
{"code" : "A", "rank" :  "1"},
{"code" : "B", "rank" :  "2"},
{"code" : "C", "rank" :  "3"},
{"code" : "D", "rank" :  "4"}
];

var members = [
{"Class": "A", "Name": "Jolly, Roger"},
{"Class": "B", "Name": "Smith, Paul"},
{"Class": "C","Name": "Jones, Jim"},
{"Class": "D","Name": "Worl, Seymour"}
];

function getRank(name) {
  var i;
  for (i = 0; i < members.length; i++)
    if (members[i].Name == name) break;
  if (i == members.length) return 9999;
  let code = members[i].Class;
  for (i = 0; i < standing.length; i++)
    if (standing[i].code == code) break;
  if (i == standing.length) return 9999;
  return parseInt(standing[i].rank);
}

function rank(name1, name2) {
  return getRank(name1) - getRank(name2);
}

console.log(splitString.sort(rank).join('|'));
Jolly, Roger|Smith, Paul|Jones, Jim|Worl, Seymour|
```

Comment: Except that a player with a rating of "0000" will be omitted from the sort.

Comment: What do you mean by a rating of "0000"? There are no 0's in the original code. Can you give me an example?

Comment: My mistake. Your code is fine. Thank you very much for your excellent work.

Comment: OK. As long as you are happy. If not I'm happy to take another look at it.

Answer (score 0):

The following code meets your ordering criteria. I didn't put the string back together; there's not enough detail in your question to address potential corner cases. But I am assuming that what you really need is just the ordering, and you can take care of reassembling the string yourself.

```
let dataString = "Worl, Seymour|Jones, Jim|Smith, Paul|Jolly, Roger|";

var standing = [
    {"code" : "A", "rank" :  "1"},
    {"code" : "B", "rank" :  "2"},
    {"code" : "C", "rank" :  "3"},
    {"code" : "D", "rank" :  "4"}
];

var members = [
    {"Class": "A", "Name": "Jolly, Roger"},
    {"Class": "B", "Name": "Smith, Paul"},
    {"Class": "C","Name": "Jones, Jim"},
    {"Class": "D","Name": "Worl, Seymour"}
];

function getOrderFromClass(lhsClass, rhsClass) {
    return getOrderFromCode(lhsClass, rhsClass);
}

function getOrderFromCode(lhsCode, rhsCode) {
  var lhsRank, rhsRank;

  for(let s of standing) {
      if(s["code"] === lhsCode) { lhsRank = s["rank"]; }
      if(s["code"] === rhsCode) { rhsRank = s["rank"]; }
  }

  if(lhsRank < rhsRank) { return -1; }
  else if(lhsRank > rhsRank) { return 1; }
  else { return 0; }
}

let splitString = dataString.split("|");
console.log(splitString);

splitString.sort(function(lhsName, rhsName) {
    var lhsClass, rhsClass;

    for(let m of members) {
        if(m["Name"] === lhsName) { lhsClass = m["Class"]; }
        if(m["Name"] === rhsName) { rhsClass = m["Class"]; }
    }

    return getOrderFromClass(lhsClass, rhsClass);
});

// All done
console.log(splitString);
```

Answer (score 0):

I will assume that all names are valid, i.e. exist in the members array, to keep the code simple.

```js
var standing = [
  { "code": "A", "rank": "1" },
  { "code": "B", "rank": "2" },
  { "code": "C", "rank": "3" },
  { "code": "D", "rank": "4" }
];
var members = [

  { "Class": "A", "Name": "Jolly, Roger" },
  { "Class": "B", "Name": "Smith, Paul" },
  { "Class": "C", "Name": "Jones, Jim" },
  { "Class": "D", "Name": "Worl, Seymour" }
];

const dataString = "Worl, Seymour|Jones, Jim|Smith, Paul|Jolly, Roger|";
// Filter out the empty string that split() produces at the end
const names = dataString.split("|").filter(name => name.length > 0);

// Map the names to members
const ms = names.map(name => members.find(m => m.Name === name));
// Map the members to standings
const ss = ms.map(m => standing.find(s => s.code === m.Class));
// Now fill the result with the names in the order of their ranking
const result = [];
names.forEach((name, i) => result[ss[i].rank - 1] = name);

for (let i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
  $("#I" + (i+1)).val(result[i]);
}
```

You seem to have some kind of indexing problem in the last part where you update the DOM elements, so I took my best guess at what you are trying to do there. But since you haven't posted your HTML, I don't know if this is exactly right.

Comment: Please see original code above with splitString not set to value.

Comment: Well from your question it looked like you wanted a string at the end. You don't need the join(). I've updated the code. I also fixed something that looks like an indexing error in your original code.

Comment: Error: {
  "message": "Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined",
  "filename": "https://stacksnippets.net/js",
  "lineno": 40,
  "colno": 7
}

Comment: $ is jQuery. Have you included jQuery from your HTML file? You seem to be struggling with basic things.

Comment: This sort of works but please see: http://verlager.com/super-dev.php because the input fields are spread out.

Comment: NOTE: click the sort icon!

Comment: N11 N21 N31 are the populated ID's in the for loop. Why I don't know.

Comment: Ah, I forgot braces around i+1

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/167972/discussion-between-verlager-and-lubo-antonov).